# jquery drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I am trying to make an app can change a dragged and dropped div's size. The div will be dropped in to the drop area were the size can be changed. The drop area is like a side wall for a house without panels and the dropped div are the panels with different colors and prices according to size.

The problem i have is keeping the original div after i have dropped the clone. Im not quite sure what im doing wrong.

```
      'http://jsfiddle.net/steven27030/JL6sL/'
```

This is the fiddle i have been working on.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to still have the original div. If yes, you should define helper: "clone" as described here http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-helper

Comment: i have a helper function so that it will look like the div i want but when i set it to clone it doesnt show like the original div. i could not get the fiddle but here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/steven27030/JL6sL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to clone the draggable. I have included the new drop function

```
drop: function (ev, ui) 
{
     var clone = ui.draggable.clone();

     var nl = $("#droppable").width();
     var nh = $("#droppable").height();
     clone.width(nl).height(nh);   

     $(this).append(clone);
}
```

and full code is available at http://jsfiddle.net/ZUtMm/

Comment: that worked but now it want delete when i hit $('button').click(function () {
      $('.dropped').remove();
    });